# Error when I use SqlDataReader in an another SqlDataReader

Tags: c#

I get an error

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

when I use a `SqlDataReader` in an another `SqlDataReader`. I don't know where I made a mistake and how can it be solved? The error appears when the second datareader (dr2) is executed.

```
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select agent,comm,primm from comm where a_id = '" + textBox1.Text + "' AND date >= @date1 AND date <= @date2 ", agr);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", dateTimePicker1.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", dateTimePicker2.Value);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {      
        aid = dr[0].ToString().Trim();
        comm = double.Parse(dr[1].ToString());
        busi = double.Parse(dr[2].ToString());

        cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select s_id,lvl from agnt where a_id = @a_id", agr);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_id", aid);

        // on this line get executed I get a message 
        // There is already an open DataReader associated with this 
        // Command which must be closed first.
        dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();         

        if(dr2.Read())
        {
            abc = dr2[0].Tostring();
        }                  
        dr2.Close();
    }

    dr.Close();
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Please show your connection string (you can mask private parts) you probably did not set up your connection string for multiple connections

Comment: Try to use two different connection objects each of data reader

Comment: @ProgrammersOcean - That is wrong, he needs a change to his connection string

Answer (score 3):

When you open a DataReader, the connection is used exclusively by the DataReader and cannot be used to execute other commands (`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`, `SqlDataAdapter` etc..).
[See the remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) on the MSDN reference on SqlDataReader.
You need to add [MultipleActiveResultSets=True](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/enable-mars/) to your connection string to overcome this limitation

[This article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx) explain the details of this problem

As an unrelated note, please, avoid to use a string concatenation to build your command text. You are already using parameters, so why do you switch to string concat for just one value?

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select agent,comm,primm from comm " + 
         "where a_id = @id AND date >= @date1 AND date <= @date2 ", agr);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", dateTimePicker1.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", dateTimePicker2.Value);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 1):

Four ways of fixing is:

1. Look at @Steve answer
2. create new connection for second data reader
3. store data from first reader and then fill it up with second reader
4. combine your query:

   ```
   select c.agent, c.comm, c.primm, a.s_id, a.lvl
   from comm c
   left join agnt a on a.a_id = c.agent
   where a_id = @a_id AND date >= @date1 AND date <= @date2
   ```

this one does not need two readers to retrieve all data from DB.

Answer (score 0):

afaik, the single connection can't be used by two datareaders at the same time. you're need to create connection for each command or use second reader after closing the first one.

Comment: here is nothing about used version of ms sql server in the question. MARS is available in 2005 and later. in this case common answer - another connection.

Comment: Bad argument: we're in year 2013. Common answer: use MARS.

Comment: yes, more common answer. but mine is more correct - by the text of question. :)

Comment: Wrong, wrong. By the text of the question you could just change the connection string in the Web.config to allow MARS and that's all. Your answer is valid for .NET 1.x early days ;) But this is StackOverflow, you can provide your own point of view and I suspect that's the reason of your answer having 0 upvotes... you know!